# How to stop duplicate values from being entered in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        lineOne[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"");

        if (lineOne[i] > 47 || lineOne[i] < 1)//Number also have to be inside these parameters 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again!!!");
            lineOne[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: there's a severe lack of 'question' in this question

Comment: So, check to see if a value already exists before storing it, then.

Comment: In what way does this code attempt to prevent duplicate values?  In what way is it failing?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array use a Set.

**Example:**

```
Set<Integer> numbers=new HashSet<>();
```

Then add the numbers to the set. It will not allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your if-statement. The way the code is written if the entered value is outside the 1-47 range, you asked for the value again. But if, again, an "incorrect" value is given, you keep it in the array and go back to the top of the for-loop.

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        lineOne[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"");

        while (lineOne[i] > 47 || lineOne[i] < 1) { //Number also have to be inside these parameters 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again!!!");
            lineOne[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code isn't working. you can still enter duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean b = true;
    int[] lineOne = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        b = true;
        int k = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ""));
        for (int j : lineOne) {
            if (k == j) {
                System.out.println("error");
                b = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (b && k < 47 && k > 1) {
            lineOne[i] = k;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Duplicate value or value out of bounds.");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

this is the best way i could think of. boolean determines whether or not the value already exists

Comment: Thanks I've used something similar to this and it works perfectly